# How to make horizontal lines on a grouped bar chart that also display the average values corresponding to each group and the legends?

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, data-visualization, bar-chart

my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

category <- c("apple", "apple", "apple","orange", "orange","orange")
mean_diameter_cm <- c(5.2,6.4,6.0, 9.2,8.6,8.1)
location <- c("Farm A","Farm B", "Farm C","Farm A","Farm B", "Farm C")
myfruit_data <- data.frame(category, mean_diameter_cm, location)

myfruit_data %>% 
    group_by(category, location) %>% 
    summarise(average_diameter = mean(mean_diameter_cm)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=location, y=average_diameter, fill=category)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

my bar graph
[image]

I tried manually calculated the averages for each group, added horizontal lines and colors like this:

```
geom_line() +
geom_hline(yintercept = mean_diameter_cm,
          color = c("green","red"))
```

The problem with this approach is I don't know how to manually add the corresponding legends and make average values display, and even if I do, it seems a bit too complicated for a not so sophisticated task, so I am thinking there must be simpler approach done by some functions that I am unaware of, which is why I am asking here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a column named `average_diameter`.  Please note that the `ggplot` is using the `mean_diameter_cm` from the object created outside as `summarise` doesn't return that column.  What is `mean_weekday`?

Comment: oh...it was a copy and paste typo from another similar problem that I am working with...just edited it.

Comment: But, still you are using `ggplot(aes(x=location, y=mean_diameter_cm, fill=category))` whereas there is average_diameter created

Comment: Also, your average_diameter is just the same as mean_diameter_cm as there is only one value per group

Comment: Is using `y=mean_diameter_cm` a huge problem? Anyway I will change it just to play safe.

Comment: Suppose you didn't have that object created in the env, the code breaks

Comment: I will update the code once again to make sure my code is bug free! Thanks for your input!

Comment: Did you meant something like `myfruit_data %>% group_by(category) %>% mutate(avg = mean(mean_diameter_cm)) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(colr = case_when(category == "apple" ~ "red", TRUE ~ "green")) %>% ggplot(aes(x=location, y=mean_diameter_cm, fill=category)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") + geom_line() + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = avg, colour = colr))`

Comment: Just tried it and this works!

Comment: one more question...how should I add to the code in order to display the average values(y-intercepts) of two lines?

Comment: you meant adding value with `geom_text`?

Comment: i don't know if `geom_text()` can achieve that..

Comment: where do you want to display those values

Comment: The best place I can think of is on the lines, kinda like `--------5.9---------`, but if it is too difficult then I can settle for other locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
myfruit_data %>% 
    group_by(category) %>%
    mutate(avg = mean(mean_diameter_cm)) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    mutate(colr = case_when(category == "apple" ~ "green",
          TRUE ~ "red")) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=location, y=mean_diameter_cm, fill=category)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
        geom_line() + 
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = avg, colour = colr)) + 
        guides(color = FALSE)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks akrun! Though I like the one you wrote in the comments slightly better, because it also displays the legends.

Comment: @mathguy I removed the leggend in the last line `guides(color = FALSE)` in case you find lots of legend distracting

Comment: I see. So the `guides(color=FALSE)` corresponds to the color legends.

Comment: @mathguy if you remove that, it will display again

Comment: @mathguy you can add `+ geom_text(aes(2, avg, label = avg, vjust = -.1))`

Comment: thanks for your answer! Looks like I need to learn more about the parameters in the `aes()` and in `geom_text()`

Comment: So I removed the `guide()` and found out in the legend, the text `green` is associated with the color red. I guess I really should remove the legends.

Comment: @mathguy you can add `+scale_colour_identity(guide = "legend")`

Comment: I added it and color of the horizontal lines now follow that in the legend, but since the color in the legend is not correct, so is the color of horizontal line now. Guess it is better to hide the legends to save time.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit unsure what you want but maybe this?

```
ggplot(myfruit_data, aes(x=location, y=mean_diameter_cm, fill = category)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +   geom_hline(data = myfruit_data %>%                              
                                                group_by(category) %>%                      
                                                summarise_at(vars(mean_diameter_cm),           
                                                             list(Mean = mean)), aes(yintercept = Mean, color = category))
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty much! Thanks for your input!